# How to keep the values same when trying to drag and release the items into the same baskets

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I can Drag and drop the images into the baskets.But the Value goes to minus points when I try to drag and release the image from Basket 1 to Basket 1.And the value goes to plus points when I try to drag and release the image from Basket 2 to Basket 2.

For example when I try to drag and release the watermelon image from basket 1 to basket 1 the points decrease by 30.

And when I try to drag and release the items from the basket 2 into the basket 2 the value goes to plus points .

How to keep the values same when trying to drag and release the items into the same baskets

Here is a Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myscore=0;
function dragStart(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,0,0);
return true;
}
function dragEnter(ev) {
event.preventDefault();
return true;
}
function dragOver(ev) {
return false;
}
function dragDrop1(ev) {

var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
ev.stopPropagation();
var cal=0;
switch(src){
case "image1": cal = 20; break;
case "image2": cal = 30; break;
case "image3": cal = 40; break;
case "image4": cal = 50; break;
case "image5": cal = 60; break;
default: cal=10;
}

myscore=myscore-cal;
document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
return false;
}
function dragDrop2(ev) {

var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
ev.stopPropagation();
var cal=0;
switch(src){
case "image1": cal = 20; break;
case "image2": cal = 30; break;
case "image3": cal = 40; break;
case "image4": cal = 50; break;
case "image5": cal = 60; break;
default: cal=10;
}
myscore=myscore+cal;
document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
return false;
}

</script>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9w4w1sr/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myscore=0;
function dragStart(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,0,0);
return true;
}
function dragEnter(ev) {
event.preventDefault();
return true;
}
function dragOver(ev) {
return false;
}
function dragDrop1(ev) {

var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
if(!ev.target.contains(document.getElementById(src))){
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
ev.stopPropagation();
var cal=0;
switch(src){
case "image1": cal = 20; break;
case "image2": cal = 30; break;
case "image3": cal = 40; break;
case "image4": cal = 50; break;
case "image5": cal = 60; break;
default: cal=10;
}
myscore=myscore-cal;
document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
}
return true;
}
function dragDrop2(ev) {

var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
if(!ev.target.contains(document.getElementById(src))){
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
ev.stopPropagation();
var cal=0;
switch(src){
case "image1": cal = 20; break;
case "image2": cal = 30; break;
case "image3": cal = 40; break;
case "image4": cal = 50; break;
case "image5": cal = 60; break;
default: cal=10;
}
myscore=myscore+cal;
document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
}
return true;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allow each `div` to hold it's own caloric value. You can do that with a `data-` attribute like:

```
<div id="image2" data-calories="30" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://www.farmfreshtoyou.com/media/wysiwyg/fresh_fruits/45.jpg');">
</div>
```

Create a function that, after the drag operation is complete, recalculates all of the calories of the child image divs. Something like this (untested code):

```
var children = document.getElementById("boxF").children;
var calories = 0;

for (var i in children) {
    if (children[i].nodeName == "DIV") {
        calories += parseInt(children.getAttribute("data-calories"));
    }
}

//set the total equal to calories
```